# How to get the xpath for menu in sidebar

Tags: xpath

I have to click on the `Manage Orders` option in the side bar menu. I tried with the xpath from firepath, but it is not working. Below is the code:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav nav-list" style="height: auto;">
        <!-- BEGIN Search Form -->
        <li>
            <!-- END Search Form -->
            <li class="active" data-slug="dashboard">
                <li data-slug="order">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"/>
                        <span>Manage Orders</span>
                        <b class="arrow fa fa-angle-down"/>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="submenu" style="display: block;">
                        <li data-slug="promocode">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="https://bq.training/cp/promocode">
                                <span>Promo Code</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-slug="transaction">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="https://bq.training/cp/order/list-order">
                                <span>Order Summary</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Comment: is this using selenium?

Comment: Yes. I'm using selenium webdriver.

Comment: public WebElement ManageOrders(WebDriver driver, String element) {
  
  WebElement WebElement;
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
  return WebElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(element)));
  
 } 
 
 
 @Test
 
 public void Orders() {
  String element = "//*[contains(text(), 'Manage Orders')]";
  ManageOrders(driver, element).click();
 }
}  I tried the above code. It is not happening.

Comment: I'm new to selenium. I'm not sure whether the above code is correct or not.

Comment: yeah the code looks fine, how you initialising the driver, does that work?

Comment: The scenario is I have to login to the application, then click on sidebar menu options. The login function is working. after that clicking on manage orders is not working.

Comment: i think you need to refocus the page, it is probably still looking for manage orders on the login page

Comment: driver.switchTo().window(-1);

Comment: hopefully should work

Comment: use that before you call for the element, its focuses driver onto current page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Xpath =

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Manage Orders')]
```

Use a function like this, is written is c#, just modify slightly.

```
public IWebElement WaitElement(IWebDriver driver, String element)
     {
      IWebElement WebElement;
      WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); //can be changed
      return WebElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(element)));
     }
```

call it like

```
WaitElement(driver, elementXpath).click();
```

Comment: Below is the error: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at bq.AdminReports.reports(AdminReports.java:20)

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Manage Orders')]
")).click();

Comment: My code is:package bq;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AdminReports extends TestBaseAdmin {
 @Test 
 public void reports() {
    
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Manage Orders')]")).click();
  
  } 
   
 }